# Are the swarming things in Leviticus 11:29-38 the only creatures that defile other articles besides human beings?

Tags: law, leviticus, moses

After describing about five groups of unclean animals/creatures in Leviticus 11 it seems only the swarming creatures have the effect of defiling other vessels like stoves,ovens and pots besides human beings.

These "extra" vessels should be broken after coming into contact with the unclean animals/creatures.

In the other group of unclean animals/creatures there is no mention of them defiling anything other than the human beings who consume and touch them

Leviticus 11:29-34 KJV

> 29 These also shall be unclean unto you among the creeping things that creep upon the earth;  the weasel, and the mouse, and the tortoise after his kind, 30 And the ferret, and the chameleon, and the lizard, and the snail, and the mole.   31 These are unclean to you among all that creep:  whosoever doth touch them, when they be dead, shall be unclean until the even.   32 And upon whatsoever any of them, when they are dead, doth fall, it shall be unclean;  whether it be any vessel of wood, or raiment, or skin, or sack, whatsoever vessel it be, wherein any work is done, it must be put into water, and it shall be unclean until the even;  so it shall be cleansed.   33 And every earthen vessel, whereinto any of them falleth, whatsoever is in it shall be unclean;  and ye shall break it.

Do the other creatures mentioned in this chapter also defile other vessels?

Answer (score 2):

Understanding principles of biology helps to explain this one fairly well, and the principle should apply to all unclean animals and to containers in general, even of other materials, which would harbor the same risks.

An earthen vessel (e.g. a clay pot) in those times was probably not glazed.  Because it has a porous surface, it is simply not possible to properly decontaminate it.  This is why it was to be broken so that no one would unwittingly use it again and potentially be sickened by it.  But pigs, horses, dogs, eagles, and the like are unlikely to "fall" into the pot after they have died, which is why the pot is not mentioned in their context.

Essentially, the dead carcass of any unclean animal would defile an earthen vessel which, because it could not be fully cleansed afterward, must then be broken.

> And upon **whatsoever** any of them, when they are dead, doth fall, it
> shall be unclean; whether it be any vessel of wood, or raiment, or
> skin, or sack, **whatsoever vessel it be**, wherein any work is done, it
> must be put into water, and it shall be unclean until the even; so it
> shall be cleansed. (Leviticus 11:32, KJV)

The language here broadly applies the principle to vessels of all types.  In verse 33, an "earthen vessel" is singled out as different from the other kinds, making it the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Are the swarming things in Leviticus 11:29-38 the only creatures that defile other articles?

No. Leviticus 15:

> 1 The Lord said to Moses and Aaron, 2“Speak to the Israelites and say to them: ‘When any man has an unusual bodily discharge, such a discharge is unclean. 3Whether it continues flowing from his body or is blocked, it will make him unclean. This is how his discharge will bring about uncleanness:
>
> 4“ ‘Any **bed** the man with a discharge lies on will be unclean, and **anything** he sits on will be **unclean**. ...
>
> 12“ ‘A **clay pot** that the man touches must be broken, and any **wooden article** is to be rinsed with water.

An unclean man could contaminate a clay pot. The defiled pot had to be broken.

Leviticus 11:

> 13a “ ‘These are the birds you are to regard as unclean and not eat because they are **unclean**: the **eagle**

If some eagle matter came into contact with a clay pot. The clay pot became unclean and had to be broken.

There is a kind of summary statement in Lev. 20:

> 25 You are therefore to distinguish between clean and unclean animals and birds. Do not become contaminated by any **animal** or **bird**, or by anything that **crawls** on the ground; I have set these apart as unclean for you. 26You are to be holy to Me because I, the LORD, am holy, and I have set you apart from the nations to be My own.